# CSS Only Marker Shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create a *CSS* only shape that looks like a marker or guitar pick.

[image: Marker shape]

My Codepen demo I've been working from: http://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/otcem

```js
// CSS Marker
// I was attempting to make this shape in CSS. The marker on the far right is an image. Next to it is SVG. The rest are my attempts :|
// stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982066/css-only-marker-shape

// Top part is a perfect circle
// Bottom half is edges that curve out!
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 20px;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/furley_bg_@2X.png) ;
background-size: 600px 600px;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

figure:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.one {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
  background: hotpink;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.two {
  background: skyblue;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
  
.three {
 border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightgreen;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.three::before {
  content:  '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 106%;
  height: 106%;
  background: lightgreen;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
}

.four {
 border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
  background: seagreen;
  overflow-x: visible;
  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.four::before {
  content:  '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
}

.five {
  width: 80px;
  height: 102px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/t80ZS.png);
  
  /* Overlay the objective */
  /*margin-left: -80px;
 opacity: 0.6;*/
}

.svg {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="one"></figure>
<figure class="two"></figure>
<figure class="three"></figure>
<figure class="four"></figure>

<figure class="svg">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="81px" height="104px" viewBox="0 0 81 104">
    <g transform="translate(1, 1)"><path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="2" d="M78.399,39.2c0,36.998-39.199,62.599-39.199,62.599S0,76.198,0,39.2C0,17.55,17.551,0,39.2,0 C60.848,0,78.399,17.55,78.399,39.2z"/></g>
 </svg>
</figure>

<!-- Image -->
<figure class="five"></figure>
```

I've been unsuccessful in replicating the curvy edges by the point. Ideally I'd like to accomplish this with one element (+pseudo elements).

Comment: Challenging question. +1

Comment: why would you want to do this in CSS?

Comment: If the solution is already there, why not study their code a bit more?

Comment: @Spudley 1 less HTTP request (it's a large sprite because it's an animation), I won't have to create 2 different versions of the image for hi-res screens, and I want to challenge myself. Kyle - that's my code ;)

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that :D Hehe.

Comment: I still think I'd use a different solution. SVG seems like a more appropriate solution, and that can be embedded in your HTML as well.

Comment: @Spudley I did end up going with SVG instead of CSS.

Answer (score 4):

### With SVG

You can achieve the marker shape with an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction). The following example uses a path element with 2 [cubic bezier curve commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves):

```css
svg{width:80px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 80 100">
  <path d="M40 99.5 C-22.5 57.5 0 0 40 0.5 C80 0 102.5 57.5 40 99.5z" stroke-width="1" stroke="grey" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

---

### With CSS

You can also make the marker shape with CSS only using border radius, absolute positioning and 2 pseudo elements. Note that this example uses only one div element

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:80px;
  height:102px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:40px;
}
div:before, div:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  width:240px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid green;  
}
div:before{
  left:0;
  border-top-left-radius:40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:240px 110px;
}
div:after{
  right:0;
  border-top-right-radius:40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:240px 110px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="45px"
  viewBox="38 12 128 180" style="cursor:help;" >
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{ fill:#FFF;stroke:#000;stroke-width:6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{fill:#1309FF;}
 .st3{fill:#1309FF;}
 .st4{fill:#1309FF;}
 .st6{font-size:57.2285px;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M158.5,73.8c0-32.3-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4c-32.3,0-58.4,26.2-58.4,58.4c0,16.6,6.9,31.5,18,42.1
 c7.2,7.2,16.7,17.2,20.1,22.5c7,10.9,20,47.9,20,47.9s13.3-37,20.4-47.9c3.3-5.1,12.2-14.4,19.3-21.6
 C151.2,106.1,158.5,90.9,158.5,73.8z"/>
<circle class="st4" cx="100.1" cy="74.7" r="44.1"/>
   <text x="100" y="90" class="st1 st5 st6" text-anchor="middle" >12</text>
</svg>
```

This will be better OR This

```html
<svg width="32px" height="45px" viewBox="38 12 128 180" >
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#020202;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M158.5,73.8c0-32.3-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4c-32.3,0-58.4,26.2-58.4,58.4c0,16.6,6.9,31.5,18,42.1c7.2,7.2,16.7,17.2,20.1,22.5c7,10.9,20,47.9,20,47.9s13.3-37,20.4-47.9c3.3-5.1,12.2-14.4,19.3-21.6C151.2,106.1,158.5,90.9,158.5,73.8z"/>
  <circle style="fill:' + color + ';" cx="100.1" cy="74.7" r="44.1"/>
  <text x="100" y="90" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:57.2285px;fill:#FFFFFF;">12</text>
</svg>
```